# Exception has occurred: ValueError No engine for filetype: ''

Tags: python, excel, pandas

so i want to split the data based on the column's name and i can't seem to know what is wrong

```
    import pandas as pd   
from pathlib import Path
import os 
#separate the data into multiple workbooks based on the game name 
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\\Users\\Nesrine\\Desktop\\data\\ESport_Earnings.xlsx') #reading the dataframe
column_name = 'Genre'
replace_symbols = ['<', '>', ':', '"', '/', '\\\\', '|', '\?', '\!', '\*', '\]', '\+', '\(', '\)', '®', '_', '-','.']
df[column_name] = (
    df[column_name].replace(replace_symbols, '', regex=True).str.strip().str.title()
)

unique_values = df[column_name].unique() #list of unique values of that column

for unique_value in unique_values:
    df_output = df[df[column_name].str.contains(unique_value)]
    output_path = os.path.join('output', str(unique_value) + '.xlsx')
    df_output.to_excel(output_path, sheet_name=unique_value, index=False)
```

and then i get the following error
Exception has occurred: ValueError No engine for filetype: ''

Comment: WHERE do you get that error?  Show the whole traceback.

Comment: Is "ESport_Earnings.xlsx" really a CSV file?  Or is it an Excel spreadsheet, as the extension suggests?

Comment: Exception has occurred: ValueError
No engine for filetype: ''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "C:\Users\Nesrine\Desktop\data\data.py", line 28, in <module>
    df_output.to_excel(output_path, sheet_name=unique_value, index=False)

Comment: @TimRoberts it is a csv file and i have changed it to excel using this   
data_frame = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\\Nesrine\\Desktop\\data\\ESport_Earnings.csv',encoding= 'unicode_escape') 

data_frame.to_excel(r'C:\\Users\\Nesrine\\Desktop\\data\\ESport_Earnings.xlsx', index=None, header=True)

Comment: You must have either `openpyxl` or `xlsxwriter` installed to do the writing.  If you know which one you have, pass `engine="xlsxwriter"` (or the other) as a parameter to `to_excel`.

Comment: @TimRoberts after adding the engine i'm having this error Title must have at least one character

Comment: Have you printed `unique_value` to make sure it is what you think it is?